# NodeJs require('path')

Tags: node.js

I have 3 files 
main,
userInfo and
getInfo

userInfo include this code:

```
 exports.module = {
       name:'',
       age:0
    }
```

main include this code:

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
userInfo.name='someName';
```

getInfo include this code:

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
console.log(userInfo.name);
```

the log does not give me the value of name, is there any way to keep the structure of the file but to add and get values to userInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you want to create a config like file or some sort of temp data storage. You cannot edit a module dynamically in nodejs but what you can do is create a json file instead, edit the content like you would an object and save the file. checkout the sample code

```
const jsonFile = require('./userInfo');
let fs = require('fs');

// Before edit
console.log(jsonFile.name);

jsonFile.name = 'John Does';

// After edit
console.log(jsonFile.name);

fs.writeFile('./userInfo.json', JSON.stringify((jsonFile)), (err) => {
  if (err) {
     return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think it will.
is there is any way beside using fs?

Comment: @M.Amer There could be, but based on my experience, this is one way I know, but you can check out the official docs for nodejs fileSystem here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use module.exports instead of exports.module

In your code, the getInfo file is never used. You won't have any output.

This code give someName as output:

main:

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
require('./getInfo');
console.log(userInfo.name);
```

userInfo:

```
module.exports = {
    name:'',
    age:0
}
```

getInfo:

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
userInfo.name='someName';
```

Consider explaining what you want to do in order to help better.

Comment: Thanks. I think I just mistype module.exports the main issue is that I want to write to userInfo object from main.js file and read it from getInfo.js file